# Combine multiple images and save the result

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to make an app where the User can move two images on the screen.
The images should overlay another. When the user has finished the movement of the images, he should be able to save the result as one image.

I do not know the following:
-how to allow the user to move images with the finger on the screen?
-how to save the images as one image in the internal device storage

Thank you very much.

Comment: We can't make your code. Show us what you've done

Comment: I do not have any clue how to start. Do I use 2 Image-Views? I dont know if I can merge this 2 images to one Image

Comment: You can use two ImageView and generate a single Bitmap using their container's drawingCache for example

Comment: Would you mind showing mean example of the drawingCache for two Image-Views please?